# load more&progress bar for RecyclerView using database from MySql <Android Studio Java>

Tags: android-recyclerview, pagination, android-loader

I am confused about how load more&progress bar for loading can be implemented inside recyclerview.

My app gets array of objects from data server.
Should I get all the data at once?(if there are 300k rows to be retrieved, you retrieve all the rows at once?)
or get portion of data and ask more from server each time when user reached the set limit(it retrieve 20 rows from server and when user scroll down the screen, my app request from data server for another 20 rows).
I want my app to be scalable. I expect a lot of data to be retrieved.